# Daterange validation for multiple from-to dates in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, datetimepicker, date-range

I have done the date range validation of a start date and end date.

**html**

```
  <label for="startdate" class="control-label">StartDate</label>

    <input type="text" id="startdate" class="form-control" />

 <label for="enddate">EndDate</label>

    <input type="text" id="enddate" class="form-control" />
```

**jquery**

```
       $(function () {

        $('#startdate,#enddate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            minDate: moment()
        });
        $('#startdate').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var incrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
            incrementDay.add(1, 'days');
            $('#enddate').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(incrementDay);
            $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
        });

        $('#enddate').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var decrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
            decrementDay.subtract(1, 'days');
            $('#startdate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(decrementDay);
             $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
        });

    });
```

This code is working properly. But I need to set another start date and end date dynamically.

The validation for this is like the first end date less than the second start date and the second end date less than the third start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** html **

```
<div class="multi-field">
  <div class="form-group m-l-0 m-r-0 col-md-4">
     <label>Start Date </label>
       <div class='input-group date' id='startdate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name='startdate_1' id='startdate_1' placeholder='Start Date' value=""/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        </span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-l-0 m-r-0 col-md-4">                   
      <label>End Date </label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='priceend'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name='priceend_1' id='priceend_1' placeholder='End Date' value="" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group m-l-0 m-r-0 col-md-3">   
<button type="button" class="add_field_button btn btn-info " id="add-field">Add Price</button>
</div>
```

** jquery **

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;

        $('#startdate_1,#priceend_1').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          useCurrent: false
     });

     $('#startdate_1').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
         var incrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
         incrementDay.add(1, 'days');
         $('#priceend_1').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(incrementDay);
         $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
     });

     $('#priceend_1').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
         var decrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
         decrementDay.subtract(1, 'days');
         $('#startdate_1').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(decrementDay);
          $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
     });



    var incre=2;
    $('#add-field').click(function(){
    counter += 1;     
    incre += 1; 
    //alert(counter)  
  $('.multi-field').append('<div class="form-group m-l-0 m-r-0 col-md-4"><label>Start Date </label><div class="input-group date" id="startdate"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="startdate_' + counter + '" id="startdate_' + counter + '" placeholder="Check-in date" value=""/><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></div><div class="form-group m-l-0 m-r-0 col-md-4"><label>End Date </label><div class="input-group date" id="priceend"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="priceend_' + counter + '" id="priceend_' + counter + '" placeholder="priceend" value="" /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></div><br/>' );
    $('#startdate_'+counter +',#priceend_'+counter).datetimepicker({
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
       useCurrent: false
   });

   var newdec= counter;
   newdec -=1;
    var decrementDay1 =  $('#priceend_'+newdec).val();
    var decrementDay1 = moment(new Date(decrementDay1));
       decrementDay1.add(1, 'days');
     $('#startdate_'+counter).data('DateTimePicker').minDate(decrementDay1);


      $('#startdate_'+counter).datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
     var decrementDay1 =  $('#startdate_'+counter).val();
    var decrementDay1 = moment(new Date(decrementDay1));
       decrementDay1.add(1, 'days');
     $('#priceend_'+counter).data('DateTimePicker').minDate(decrementDay1);

     });
            $("#count_c").val(counter);
    });
 $("#count_c").val(counter);
```

});

please refer this js fiddle for further clarification,
 {{https://jsfiddle.net/1oLtoum2/2/}}